# How to get a Single Record from a KafkaStream Ktable Ktable join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 2 ktables (T1 and T2), and I am performing a KTable-KTable join on them and the processing that gets triggered as a result will send a tombstone to T1 at the end so it won't trigger again.

The behaviour I want is that:

1. Messages can arrive in T1 and T2 out of order, unwindowed - hence using the table/table join
2. If a batch of messages arrived with the same key for T2, the processing should only be triggered ONCE, with the latest message for T2.

The problem:

Initially, I was seeing the processing getting triggered TWICE, with a single message for T1 and T2.   Upon googling, I found that this is related to the caching behaviour in kafka stream -> [Kafka streams - joining two ktables invokes join function twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429868/kafka-streams-joining-two-ktables-invokes-join-function-twice)

So I turned off the cache as recommended, and that solved the initial problem. However, now if a batch of message arrives in T2 with the same key, its triggering the processing multiple times, once per message.

So turning off the cache lead solved one problem, but introduced another.  Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour which is really triggering the processing ONCE only per message key?

thanks!